When a popup menu is shown, Buttons are no longer pressable even engine buttons
Quick explanation: I am trying to create my own plugin in godot 4.3, and I want to use a popup menu node to instance a scene that has buttons, but for some reason when using the popup menu, and pressing a option on the menu, I lose the ability to press any button on scene and I am not sure how I can fix this strange issue, I have spent a good 1 almost 2 hours, I also noticed that even engine based buttons no longer work, unless I do control + s which does a save, could my issue be an engine bug?
I have put the project on github : https://github.com/Dragon20C/Event-Sheet
I recommend on actually downloading the project and seeing if the issue is on my side or a global issue, thank you.
I think this is the only important script as it controls the popup menu.
@tool
extends Panel
class_name EventSheet

@onready var blank_panel : PackedScene = preload("res://addons/Event Sheet Plugin/GUI/EventBar/EventBar.tscn")
@export_subgroup("Nodes")
@export var event_container : VBoxContainer
var current_menu : String = "General"

var current_panel : EventPanel
var current_event
var current_action

var is_mouse_focused : bool = false

var popup_menus: Dictionary = {
    "general": ["Add Blank Event"],
    "blank_body": ["Add Event", "Add Action", "", "Delete Blank Event"],
    "event": ["Edit Event", "Add Event", "", "Delete Event"],
    "action": ["Edit Action", "Add Action", "", "Delete Action"]
}

@export_subgroup("PopUpNodes")
@export var popup_menu : PopupMenu

func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT and event.double_click and is_mouse_focused:
            pass
            #show_add_window("event")
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT and event.pressed and is_mouse_focused:
            show_popup_menu()

func _on_popup_menu_index_pressed(index: int) -> void:
    popup_menu.hide()
    match current_menu:
        "general":
            match index:
                0:
                    ## Add a blank panel to the window
                    var blank_event : EventPanel= blank_panel.instantiate()
                    blank_event.selected.connect(handle_panel_focus)
                    event_container.add_child(blank_event)
                    current_event = "blank_body"
                    
    #print("Index : %s" % index)

func show_popup_menu(menu: String = "general"):
    current_menu = menu
    var mouse_pos = Vector2i(get_viewport().get_mouse_position()) + get_window().position
    popup_menu.clear()
    for item in popup_menus[menu]:
        if item == "": popup_menu.add_separator()
        else: popup_menu.add_item(item)
    popup_menu.set_size(Vector2(0, 0))
    popup_menu.set_position(mouse_pos)
    popup_menu.show()

func handle_panel_focus(panel : EventPanel) -> void:
    print("Panel has focused!")
    current_panel = panel

func _on_mouse_entered() -> void:
    is_mouse_focused = true
    
func _on_mouse_exited() -> void:
    is_mouse_focused = false

